# How can I identify which device caused a `/dev` entry?

Tags: linux, partitioning

I have a Dell Inspiron 600M, from around 2004.  The partition table looks like this:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1           6       48163+  de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2   *           7        3478    27888840    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3            3479        6838    26984449    5  Extended
/dev/sda4            6839        7295     3670852+  db  CP/M / CTOS / ...
/dev/sda5            3479        6694    25824256   83  Linux
/dev/sda6            6694        6838     1159168   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Does anyone know what sda1 and sda4 are for?  I did not create them, so I imagine Dell installed them when the machine was built.

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask: you should probably be on Power User or Server Fault.

Comment: 1=Dell diagnostics, 4=Dell Restore partition.

Answer (score 0):

SDA1 is your restore partition - from which you can restore your system to a factory fresh state. I have no idea about SDA5 - it seems an odd filetype and might also be system utilities of some sort. Its an unusual location for it, since most partitions of the sort are before the main partition with the OS.